# Condition's speed in query

Tags: mysql, sql

Given both give the same result and from the same data. Does adding the condition at SELECT (CASE WHEN) make the query faster than putting it at WHERE?

```
/*On SELECT*/    
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as totaal,
            SUM(general_score_filter.dash) as totaal_score
        FROM (
        SELECT 
            operatie.id as operatie_id,
            AVG(CASE WHEN patient.inactief = 0 AND vraag.eigenschap_id = _eigenschap_id THEN antwoord.score ELSE 0 END) AS dash
        FROM
        operatie
            LEFT JOIN antwoord ON operatie.id = antwoord.operatie_id AND antwoord.deleted = 0
            LEFT JOIN vraag ON vraag.id = antwoord.vraag_id AND vraag.deleted = 0
            LEFT JOIN patient ON operatie.patient_id = patient.id AND patient.inactief = 0
        GROUP BY operatie.id) AS general_score_filter;

/*On WHERE*/
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as totaal,
            SUM(general_score_filter.dash) as totaal_score
        FROM (
        SELECT 
            operatie.id as operatie_id,
            AVG(CASE WHEN vraag.eigenschap_id = _eigenschap_id THEN antwoord.score ELSE 0 END) AS dash
        FROM
        operatie
            LEFT JOIN antwoord ON operatie.id = antwoord.operatie_id AND antwoord.deleted = 0
            LEFT JOIN vraag ON vraag.id = antwoord.vraag_id AND vraag.deleted = 0
            LEFT JOIN patient ON operatie.patient_id = patient.id AND patient.inactief = 0
        WHERE
            patient.inactief = 0
        GROUP BY operatie.id) AS general_score_filter;
```

Comment: You need to provide more context.  An example of the queries you are asking about would help.  `CASE` and `WHERE` do different things -- one changes the values of a column, the other filters rows.  So the basis of your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `case` expressions in the `where` clause, since they are harder to optimize. User `and`/`or` constructions instead.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Well, I'm just asking and I don't see any duplicate question. Now I got -2 vote. What's wrong with these people? LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the amount of your data.  Small dataset of 50k-100k, you may not notice, but if you had millions of rows, you would.

But overall, yes it would be faster in your WHERE clause with an index on the inactief status.  Based on sample data below, you would be skipping out on all the "inactief = 1" records, but also, one would be more accurate for your answer.  Do you want all people, or only those that inactief = 0.  Read more below

Example with the following records from the Operatie table

```
id    inactief      score (via the join to antwoord)
1     0             10
1     0             20
1     1             30
1     0             40
1     1             50
1     1             60
1     0             70
2     1             15
2     1             25
3     0             38
```

Assuming your first query, your final count would have all 3 patients ( 1, 2 and 3 ).  Your second count where clause of "inactief = 0" will only return 2 patients (1 and 3) since patient 2 had all their records with inactief = 1.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp, that's all what I need to know.
Sometimes things seem simple but people just want to make them complicated :)

Comment: @JuanNguyen, and a comment from someone 800k reputation could not figure out what you were asking for clarification?  I guess I did ok :)

Comment: Oh well, he just left a comment before I added an example. But he didn't come back. : (